# Trying to access Oracle DB from MS-Excel using VB script

Tags: excel, oracle, vbscript

I am trying to connect to Oracle DB using the VB script. I have added the Microsoft ODBC for Oracle on the Administrative tools also. Still I am getting the error as
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Code is as follows:

```
Sub ora_connection()
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim query As String
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    strCon = "Driver = {Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
    "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
    "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
    "(HOST= <provided the host as per TNS>)(PORT = 1521))" & _
    "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=<Provided the service_name as per the TNS>))); uid=<User id >; pwd=<password>;)"
    con.Open (strCon)
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you install an Oracle Client?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47101221/connect-excel-vba-to-oracle-again/47110182#47110182 I assume you have to define an alias in `tnsnames.ora` file.